# applying map.fitbounds()

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm making a map using openstreetmap I want to show the location of UK when the map loads at very first I'm giving a lat and lng to show the location right now but I want to use map.fitbounds() function to exactly fit the Uk location on map;

```
const myMap = L.map('map').setView([52.3555, 1.1743], 6);
//getting map tile from open source free openstreetmap tile provider
const tileUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
//setting attribution at bottom
const attribution =
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> ';
        //adding attribution layer to map
const tileLayer = L.tileLayer(tileUrl, { attribution });
tileLayer.addTo(myMap);
```

Please right a code to fit Uk location in map using fitbounds

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds)?

Comment: yeah but could not understand it well that why I asked here

Comment: It takes two sets of lat/lng coordinates. One set for the top-left corner, the second set for the bottom-right corner.